# Twitter Typeahead with Bootstrap (and without) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to get a basic twitter typeahead tooltip showing. I've followed the docs but nothing is showing up.No errors are thrown in console either.

I am using Bootstrap 3.0.3. Typeahead is supposed to be built in to it. However, I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'` error if I do not import it directly.

The way I am doing it is as follows:

```
<input name="hostname_search" id="typeahead" autocomplete="off" size=100 />
```

and for the JS:

```
 $('#typeahead').typeahead(
   {
     local: [{ val: 'dog' }, { val: 'pig' }, { val: 'moose' }]
   }
 );
```

Bootstrap's docs says we should `source` instead of `local` and in the HTML, use `data-provide`. I am using the above as that's what typeahead's actual docs show, outside of bootstrap.

Any idea what I'm missing/what I need to do to get it showing? Also, why isn't it using typeahead in Bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe http://tosbourn.com/2013/08/javascript/upgrading-from-bootstraps-typeahead-to-typeahead-js/

Comment: @Nayefc Typehead is not built-in in Bootstrap 3.0.3 anymore. You need to import the library to make it work. You can get it from the typehead.js repo at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

Comment: @Arbel You're right. I just did the conversion but it is still not showing up. All examples are showing `$('.typeahead').typeahead({` but they are not showing `class="typeahead"` in the HTML. Is the `data-provide` supposed to override that and be used as `.typeahead`, or do I need a `class` attr in the HTML? Why don't the examples show that?

Comment: @Nayefc The jQuery selector just targets the correct element for typeahead. Probably this page will give you more hint to find the problem http://tosbourn.com/2013/08/javascript/upgrading-from-bootstraps-typeahead-to-typeahead-js/

Comment: @Arbel I did follow that link. It still doesn't work. Nothing shows up. How will it target the correct element for typeahead? Does it need data-provide or the write id or the right class?

Comment: I tried all three but none work.  Are there no examples out there at all on what the HTML should be? I read the docs and I'm pretty sure the JS part is correct.